# S3 Bucket Policy help needed to additionally restrict one file to specific IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have restricted the read access on my entire bucket to specific IPs, e.g. `1.1.1.0` & `2.2.2.0` as per the bucket policy given below.

There's a file in it, `s3://MYBUCKET/onefile.txt`, to which I want to give another set of IPs read access, e.g. to `3.3.3.0` and `4.4.4.0`.  So that now `onefile.txt` can only be accessed by `3.3.3.0` and `4.4.4.0` **but NOT by** `1.1.1.0` & `2.2.2.0` or any other.

How can I accomplish that?

Current **Permissions > Bucket Policy** (e.g.)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MY RESTRICTED REQUESTS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.1.1.0/20",
                        "2.2.2.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add explicit deny and allow statements for that file `onefile.txt` in addition to the existing statement in the Policy.

The updated bucket policy would look like,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MY RESTRICTED REQUESTS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.1.1.0/20",
                        "2.2.2.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "MY RESTRICTED REQUESTS_1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/onefile.txt",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "3.3.3.0/20",
                        "4.4.4.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "MY RESTRICTED REQUESTS_2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKET/onefile.txt",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "1.1.1.0/20",
                        "2.2.2.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```